# How to add extra data to TextChoices?

Tags: django, django-models

How Can I add extra data to `django.db.models.TextChoices`?

```py
class Fruit(models.TextChoices):

    APPLE = ('myvalue', True, 'mylabel')
```

such that:

```py
>>> Fruit.APPLE.is_tasty
True
>>> # And it still works otherwise
>>> Fruit.APPLE.value
'myvalue'
>>> Fruit.APPLE.label
'mylabel'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do something similar to what the [python Enum docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init) suggest, but unlike python `Enum`, the label is already taken care of by `models.Choices`:

```py
class Fruit(models.TextChoices):

    APPLE = ('myvalue', True, 'mylabel')

    def __new__(cls, value, is_tasty):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.is_tasty = is_tasty
        return obj
```

If you use this on an `IntegerChoices`, you'll need `int.__new__`. If you use `__init__` instead of `__new__`, the enum value would become `('myvalue', True)`, which gets used in `Fruit.choices` and probably won't fit your model Field.

Though note when the choices enum is used on a model field, you never actually pass it the enum, so it's not aware of the enum. E.g. the form field derived from it with `ModelForm` will treat them as `str` values and after a POST the field value will be a regular `str`, not an enum value. For the form case you can define `MyForm.clean_fruit` or provide a manual form field `TypedChoiceField(coerce=Fruit)`, elsewhere you may need to look up the enum value again with `Fruit(value)` or you could add this mixin to your field:

```py
class EnumMixin:

    'Convert a DB value back to its Choices value'

    def __init__(self, *args, enum: models.Choices, **kwargs):
        self.__enum = enum
        # it sets choices for you using the enum
        super().__init__(*args, choices=enum.choices, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        'Get constructor args to reconstruct this field with later'
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs['enum'] = self.__enum
        del kwargs['choices']
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        # Convert from db value
        return self.__to_enum(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        'Called by deserialization and during clean() method used in forms'
        return self.__to_enum(value)

    def __to_enum(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return self.__enum(value)

class EnumCharField(EnumMixin, models.CharField):
    pass

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = EnumCharField(enum=Fruit, ...)
```

`deconstruct` is used by django migrations though note it won't reconstruct the `Enum` at the time you make the migration, it will use whatever your `Enum` is at the time you apply the migration.

#### Why not call super?

While `super().__new__` works fine in general, this is not the case for `Enum` subclasses (`models.TextChoices` is a `models.Choices` which is an `Enum`). Python docs note the following:

> The `__new__()` method, if defined, is used during creation of the Enum members; it is then replaced by Enum’s `__new__()` which is used after class creation for lookup of existing members.

So, `EnumMeta` replaces the class' `__new__` with `Enum.__new__` on `Fruit`, `TextChoices`, ... If you call `super().__new__` in `Fruit.__new__` then this calls `TextChoices.__new__` which is actually `Enum.__new__` and which will not expect the args you are passing it (and even if it did accept your args it never calls `super().__new__` itself).

It would raise:

```
ValueError: 'myvalue' is not a valid Fruit
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, should be marked Accepted.  Also, that Mixin should be turned into a package, or added to django-extensions.

Comment: Thanks, django-extensions offers additional django management commands so I don't think it'd be a good fit for that.

Comment: Doesn't it have lots of other stuff, too - including additional model field types?

Comment: You're right, I never noticed that. Seems like a good spot for it, indeed.

Comment: You saved my day. I've been trying different things for hours with limited success. It would be worthwhile to add your solution to the official Django documentation because bridging the gap from the current docs of Enum and TextChoices is far from obvious

Answer (score 0):

This `EnumMixin` seems to create a problem with serializing. I had to suppress the method `from_db_value` to be able to dumpdata to yaml!...
T