# Best way to add third attribute to Django models choices

Tags: python, django, enums

As the title suggests, what would be the best way to go about adding a third attribute to Django's model enum choice so that I could access the property in the same manner as `value` or `label`. For instance, let's call this third attribute `text`

what I want:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    class VehicleType(??):
        HONDA_CIVIC = 1, _("New car"), _("Vroom vroom")
        FORD_MODEL_T = 2, _("Old car"), _("not so fast") 

    type = models.IntegerField(choices=VehicleType.choices, default=VehicleType.FORD_MODEL_T)


vehicle = Vehicle.objects.create()
vehicle.type.text
>>> not so fast
```

Is this possible without overwriting the base [ChoicesMeta](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/enums.py)? I've tried a version as outlined in the [python enum docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init) by updating `__new__` however this doesn't seem to work. (And yes, I know I could change it to `models.TextChoices` and nix the int value, but I'm curious if this is easily possible)

Comment: today I discovered someone else had the same problem I have with Enum Choices in Django, and I also discovered I still have no solution... did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: Here is a post which brought the answer for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817673/how-to-add-extra-data-to-textchoices